# Is there a similar API in Spark with the twitter.scalding.addTrap to deal with exception

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am transplanting a project from hadoop to the Spark 2.1.0. Previously, it use twitter.scalding.addTrap to deal with exception like:
https://github.com/scalding-io/ProgrammingWithScalding/blob/master/chapter3/src/main/scala/addTrap.scala

and for Spark, I read input using sc.textFile(InputPath), but I don't know how to perform previous exception handling function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/util/Try.html).

```
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def divide: Try[Int] = {
    val dividend = Try(StdIn.readLine("Enter an Int that you'd like to divide:\n").toInt)
    val divisor = Try(StdIn.readLine("Enter an Int that you'd like to divide by:\n").toInt)
    val problem = dividend.flatMap(x => divisor.map(y => x/y))
    problem match {
        case Success(v) =>
            println("Result of " + dividend.get + "/"+ divisor.get +" is: " + v)
            Success(v)
        case Failure(e) =>
            println("You must've divided by zero or entered something that's not an Int. Try again!")
            println("Info from the exception: " + e.getMessage)
            divide
    }
}
```

Comment: I finally use collectionAccumulator to collect the exception line and save them at the end of the program. Thanks for your reply~